# Unexpected token export {} after importing cjs file in Typescript+ESM project

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs, ts-node

#### EDIT

- Changing `module` to `Node16` inside `compilerOptions` fixed it.
- more info https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50647

I have a pretty simple typescript+esm project with a CJS dependency, so my code looks like this:

index.ts

```
import myFunc from "./myfile.cjs"
(...)
```

I also have the `compilerOptions` (inside `tsconfig.json`) `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`and `esModuleInterop` set

But when I try to run it using `ts-node` (`node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node src/index.ts`) it fails with a syntax error saying that my cjs file, `myfile.cjs` has an unexpected token export (`export {};`)

It is clear to me that something (ts-node probably) is trying to convert this into an ESM module, but it just creates a syntax error and breaks the code. Obviously, I'm not adding it there manually.

Command used: `node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node src/index.ts`

Complete error log:

```
export {};
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/cjg/Git/ast/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/cjg/Git/ast/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:170:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "module": "es2020",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es2020",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
        "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

- ts-node version: 10.9.1
- node version: 17.9.0
- tsc version: 4.7.4

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several threads on this when generating code for a ".ts" file, even for a commonjs target.  From what I can tell, typescript developers think the generated export {}; is a feature in those files and provide the rationale (which many disagree with).

From your description, and I tested the same, they're doing the same in very specifically (.cjs) files.

The solution for now is to remove the line in your build.  Maybe using gulp-replace?

Comment: Hey, I ended up finding this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50647 where the exact same problem is reported.  Changing the `module` option inside `compilerOptions` fixed it.